# Is there any option in the python debugger to modify a line in the code while executing it, or to skip execution of some line?

Tags: python, pdb, edit-and-continue

If I realize that some line of my code will throw a runtime error while running the code in debug mode, I would like to save my time by correcting the code at a breakpoint. I could manually type the correct line of code and execute it, but when I run "next", It would still run the erroneous line and throw the runtime error. When this happens, I would have to start all over again. Is there any way to correct the code on the go while running the code line-by-line? This would help many people save a lot of time.